# Is there a way to link to the BOTTOM of the comments on a wordpress page?

Tags: comments, links

We're using a free account on wordpress.com.  On our site's main page, we have this HTML:

`To contact us <a href="#comments">send us a message in a comment</a>.`

Clicking on this link takes you to the top of the comments section at the bottom of the page.

On some pages, there are a lot of comments, and we'd like to have a link that bypasses all of the existing comments and jumps to the end of the comments.  Is there a way to link to the BOTTOM of the comments section?

[Click on this link to visit our web page, which uses this HTML code.](https://tucsonpetanqueclub.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Please post the code you're using (or link to your site if you're comfortable with that) so we can see what we're dealing with.

Comment: Done.  I've edited my original question to show code and provide a link.

Comment: Why not simply insert another anchor _after_ the comments, and link to that?

Comment: @tripleee because it's a WordPress.com account they may not have access to the source code, so they'll need to work within the existing framework. Thankfully the 'respond' section has an anchor link, and we can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the code.

Give this a shot:

```
To contact us <a href="#respond">send us a message in a comment</a>.
```

Comment: Excellent! It works!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please upvote and select my answer as solving your issue.

Comment: I've found an even better method... use the "#comment" link.  Note that it is singular... "#comment", not "#comments".